# How to change message in devise.en.yml file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My rails 3 app uses `devise.en.yml` file.

As soon as a user signs up, devise flashes the following prompt which I need to change

```
"Invalid email or password".
```

This above message i have changed like `"Invalid username or password"` in devise.en.yml file,but still it displays the wrong message

Does anyone know how to change this flash message?

Comment: You can put custom message in config/locales/en.yml.
And where your devise.en.yml is located?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have changed it in the right instance:

> devise: > failure: > invalid: "Invalid username or password"

Also, you would need to restart the server after the change.